# Combining two surfaces gives a hollow object

Tags: export, extrude, stl

Blender 3.6.4 on Linux.

I've made 2 surfaces with the "Mesh/Math Function/Z Math Surface" add-on (from "Add Mesh: Extra Objects")

They have the same size (x-y), and are on top of each other.

I selected a first border of the first surface, and the corresponding from the second, and hit 'f', to make a face between two 2.
I repeated this for the 3 other borders, and got what seems to be an enclosed volume.

[image]

If I try to substract a cube from it, I can see that it is hollow (no surface is made where the cube is substracted)

[image]

If I export it in stl and load it in Cura, the gap in the first function are partially "filled", floored at the level of the 0 of the lower function (see image)

[image]
[image]

How can I "fill" between the two surfaces, so that I can later substract volumes,... like I can do with "regular" meshes (sphere, cylinders,...) ?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Are the normals of your combined surface all facing outward? (Perhaps the bottom half is inside-out with respect to the enclosed volume).. (Alt-N)

Comment: The "fills" are obviously created in Cura to make the model stable enough for printing.
What Cura does, Blender cannot prevent.

```
How can I "fill" between the two surfaces, so that I can later substract volumes,.... like I can do with "regular" meshes (sphere, cylinders,...) ?
```
What do you mean by this?
When or how do you want to do `later` something with it? In Cura?
This is Blender Stack exchange. We don't know and can't answer questions about Cura.

Comment: Let me try to clarify. If I make a sphere and substract a cylinder from it (using a boolean modifier), I can see that blender created surfaces where the cylinder surface intersected the sphere. The resulting partial sphere is closed.

But with my volume here, no such surfaces where made when I substracted a cube (you can see the inside of the shape in the screenshot). It seems like Blender considers my object hollow, when the sphere is considered full, but maybe that just my impression and not the correct explanation.

Comment: I suspect that my model has something wrong, but I don't know why. I have two reasons to suspect that: (1) when substracting a cube, it doesn't do what I expected (see above), and (2) Cura doesn't handle the resulting shape as it should.
With (2°only, I would suspect Cura, but (1) is fully in blender, so I think that it's a problem with my model. 
Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @RobinBetts : thank you. In edit mode, I displayed the face orientation (via "Overlays menu), and half of it was red, half blue. Then I display the normals (via ame overlays menu), I could see that the ones from my surface below where ponting inward.

To correct: enter edit mode, select all ('a'), do 'alt-N' and select 'recalculate outside' => now substracting a cube works as expected!

Because the model is now correct, Cura could also slice it as it should, it doesn't fill anything that shouldn't be.

Thanks to all for your time and suggestions!